# How to achieve automations with superputty?

Tags: putty

I need to do automations like auto-login and sending repetative commands. Currently I do autologin into putty by creating a shotcut of "putty.exe"  and then by editing its target under properties as belows {"putty.exe_path" -ssh @ -pw }

You can refer the youtube link : https://youtu.be/Ld9MPbkVLrc

Now I got few scripts to run repetatively for my day to day job. Hence I require details on automation tools for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an alternative application KiTTy_portable.exe which is just under 500KB. Using it i can currently automatically login and send a few basic commands like changing a directory,  clearing the screen post login,  call & execute few scripts and send script on my desktop to server with just a few clicks.